# $|G:H|=2$, $K \leq G$ with an element not in $H$. Prove $HK=G$

Tags: group-theory

I know it has something to do with normal subgroups and cosets partitioning, but I don't know how to deal with cosets of $HK$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $H$ has index $2$, it is a normal subgroup. This implies that $HK$ is a subgroup. (In general it is a subset). But $H \subsetneq HK \subseteq G$, where the first inclusion is strict because $K$ has an element not in $H$. Comparing indices it follows that $G=HK$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in K$ with $x \notin H$. Since index$[G:H]=2$, we have $G = H \cup Hx$. Now let $g \in G$ be arbitrary. Then either $g \in H \subseteq HK$. Or $g \in Hx \subseteq HK$. So either way, $g \in HK$. Hence $G$ lies in the subset $HK$. But of course $HK \subseteq G$. It follows that $G=HK$.